# how do I update TFS test results by configuration?

Tags: tfs, mtm

I have a method that seems to be working to update a TFS test result ONLY for the configuration that it ran on.  But it seems very inefficient.  Can someone help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong? - specifically it doesn't seem that I should have to get testSuites for a given test ID, then iterate through all tests for those suites to compare to the test ID I already have.

As an example, I run a test against Windows 8/Chrome.  So TestContext contains the appropriate values that map to a configuration.  I want to update the test result for that configuration in every test suite that it exists in.  Here is the code:

```
    public void UpdateResult(TestContext context, bool passed)
    {
        int testCaseID = Convert.ToInt32(context.Test.Properties["id"]);

        TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri);

        ITestManagementService service = projectCollection.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
        ITestManagementTeamProject teamProject = service.GetTeamProject(teamProjectName);

        ITestCase testCase = teamProject.TestCases.Find(testCaseID);
        ITestSuiteCollection testSuites = teamProject.TestSuites.ReferencingTestCase(testCaseID);

        if (testCase != null)
        {
            // ---- Get Test Plan
            int testPlanId = 20589;
            ITestPlan testPlan = teamProject.TestPlans.Find(testPlanId);

            // ---- Create Test Run
            ITestRun testRun = teamProject.TestRuns.Create();
            testRun = testPlan.CreateTestRun(true);

            // ---- Get TestPoint
            ITestPointCollection points = testPlan.QueryTestPoints("SELECT * FROM TestPoint WHERE TestCaseId =" + testCaseID);
            foreach (ITestPoint tp in points)
            {
                //Get configuration, which contains configuration values
                ITestConfiguration testConfiguration = teamProject.TestConfigurations.Query("Select * from TestConfiguration WHERE Name='" + tp.ConfigurationName + "'")[0];
                IDictionary<string, string> testConfigValues = testConfiguration.Values;

                if ((!testConfigValues.ContainsKey("Browser") ||
                    testConfigValues["Browser"].ToLower() == context.Test.Properties["Browser"].ToString().ToLower())
                    && (!testConfigValues.ContainsKey("Operating System") ||
                    testConfigValues["Operating System"].ToLower() == context.Test.Properties["Operating System"].ToString().ToLower())
                   )
                {
                    testRun.AddTestPoint(tp, testPlan.Owner);
                }

            }

            testRun.State = TestRunState.Completed;
            testRun.Save();

            foreach (ITestSuiteBase testSuite in testSuites)
            {
                foreach (ITestSuiteEntry testCse in testSuite.TestCases)
                {
                    ITestCaseResultCollection results = testRun.QueryResults();
                    if (testCse.TestCase.Id == testCaseID)
                    {

                        foreach (IdAndName config in testCse.Configurations)
                        {
                            IEnumerable<ITestCaseResult> testCaseResults = from tr in results
                                                                           where
                                                                           tr.TestConfigurationId == config.Id &&
                                                                           tr.TestCaseId == testCase.Id
                                                                           select tr;

                            foreach (ITestCaseResult result in testCaseResults)
                            {
                                result.Outcome = passed ? TestOutcome.Passed : TestOutcome.Failed;
                                result.State = TestResultState.Completed;
                                result.Save(true);
                            }
                        }
                    }


                }
            }

            testRun.Save();
            testRun.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting test result, you could directly get test result by test ID. For example:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection teamCollection;
            ITestManagementService service;
            ITestManagementTeamProject project;
            var picker = new TeamProjectPicker(TeamProjectPickerMode.SingleProject, false);
            picker.ShowDialog();
            if (picker.SelectedTeamProjectCollection != null && picker.SelectedProjects != null)
            {
                teamCollection = picker.SelectedTeamProjectCollection;
                service = teamCollection.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
                project = service.GetTeamProject(picker.SelectedProjects.First().Name);
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

//Get Test result
 var testResults = project.TestResults.ByTestId([test case id]);

 // iterate each result for the case
 foreach (ITestCaseResult result in testResults)
 {
     //TODO other code
     //update result
     result.Outcome = TestOutcome.Failed;
     result.Save(true);
}
```

Also add some links about related TFS API that may help you for your reference:

- [Code snippets on Test Management APIs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aseemb/archive/2012/08/07/code-snippets-on-test-management-apis.aspx)
- [Test case result using TFS API](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5bfa18d1-44f0-4abf-915b-671ee92e443e/is-there-a-way-for-me-to-use-the-api-to-update-the-results-passfail-for-a-particular-test-case-in?forum=vsmantest)

Comment: Since this has to be programmatic, the picker doesn't benefit me much. So I'm assuming the helpful part is getting testResults ByTestId.  That's helpful and good to know but it doesn't solve my problem I don't think?  My issue is updating for all configurations unless I do that monstrosity I posted.  How do I incorporate ONLY updating a select configuration in your code?  Also, don't I have to call AddTestPoint?

Comment: do you have more information to help with my comment?  I've seen those links you gave - neither talk about how you incorporate configurations into the updates.